# How to differentiate between unexpected keyword argument and missing positional argument TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a function below, how can I differentiate between these two `TypeError`?

```
def test_method(a):
    print(a)

test_method(a=1) # 'a'
test_method() # TypeError: test_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
test_method(a=1, b=2) # TypeError: test_method() got an unexpected keyword argument 'b'
```

I'd like to do something like psuedocode

```
try:
    test_method()
except TypeError(MissingPositionalArgument):
    do_something()
except TypeError(UnexpectedKeywordArgument):
    do_something_else()
```

Comment: `test_method()` will never raise the unexpected-keyword-argument variety of `TypeError`. You seem to be trying to handle errors at runtime that are best treated as bugs to be fixed *before* running the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the text of the exception message:

```
try:
    some_function()
except TypeError as ex:
    if 'some text' in str(ex):
        # handle it...
    elif 'some other text' in str(ex):
        # handle it...
```

Comment: Will likely accept. That was my original idea, didn't know if there was a way to further differentiate beyond `TypeError` with a built-in